# C# Dictionary Composition

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, functional-programming, composition

Let's say I have an arbitray list of A

```
class A
{
string K {get;set;}
string V {get;set;}
}

...
List<A> theList = ...
```

Is there an easy way to compose a dictionary from theList? (something like the following)

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = magic(x => x.K, x => x.V, theList)
```

I don't want to write the following code:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>
foreach(var blah in theList)
    d[blah.K] = blah.V
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's this: [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx).

You use it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = theList.ToDictionary(e => e.K, e => e.V);
```

Comment: Nice. I learned something new, too. But I think it should be `e => e.V`.

Comment: @Joel B Fant: No, it shouldn't be `e => e.V`. Doing that will key the dictionary on V, with the values being the instances of A.

Comment: He means that for the second parameter, it should be a lambda (=>) instead of an equals (=).  Just a typo.

Comment: Ai, yes, thanks for the edit, of course it should be the lambda operator.

Answer (score 4):

If the list is an `IEnumerable<A>` then most definitely.  You would use the ToDictionary extension method on the Enumerable class in the System.Linq namespace in .NET 3.5 and beyond like so:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = theList.ToDictionary(a => a.K, a => a.V);
```

Which will give you a Dictionary where the key is the value in the K property, and the value is the value in the V property.

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumarable.ToDictionary<TSource,TKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) is what you are looking for:

```
theList.ToDictionary(x => x.K, x => x.V);
```

Comment: Just as a point of clarification, it's `Enumerable.ToDictionary`, not `IEnumerable.ToDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dict = theList.Cast<A>().ToDictionary(a => a.K, a => a.V);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = theList.ToDictionary( x => x.K , x=> x.V);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

theList.ForEach( param => dict[param.K] = param.V );
```

A little shorter, but still basically a `for-each` loop. I like the `ToDictionary()` solution better.

Comment: @Joel B Fant: No reason to do this since LINQ provides the ToDictionary extension method for you.

Comment: Agreed, but I didn't know about that one until now.